# Adding a listen live button to a site?

Tags: streaming

I need a service from some company where I can just provide the frequency and country (in this case Namibia, and whatever fm) and have them actual provide the live streaming?

Is this possible? Os is a shoutcast server the best way to go?

Answer (score 1):

You really need to stream it over the internet - it is quite easy to do, either by shoutcast as you say or another streaming suite.

Simply output as a stream to a server and allow other people to connect - shoutcast would probably be easiest and other people will be able to listen from a number of media players.

Comment: But is there no company that offers this as a service for us guys that can't set up servers to stream stuff?